# if title of selected option equals classname of div

Tags: jquery

Hello I have found a lot about "selected options equals", but I dont manage to solve the following problem. The idea is, to show the divs only, if their classname equals the title of the selected option.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="group_5" id="group_5" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">
  <option value="bitte" selected="selected" title="fake">Bitte wählen</option>
  <option value="35" title="Stoffbeutel">Stoffbeutel 28</option>
  <option value="36" title="Plastikbeutel">Plastikbeutel 28</option>
</select>

<div class="lagerbestand-attribute">
  <div class="Stoffbeutel"> Stoffbeutel: 5 Stücke</div>
  <div class="Plastikbeutel"> Plastikbeutel: 5 Stücke</div>
</div>
```

Is this possible with jquery? Please note, that I can't use the direct solution like: if($(this).val() == 'Stoffbeutel')

I need it somehow with help of title oder classname...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward using jquery. Hide both divs, and when the dropdown changes find the appropriate one to show and hide all the others.

```js
$('.lagerbestand-attribute div').hide();
$('select').change(function(){
    $('.lagerbestand-attribute div.' + $(':selected',this).attr('title')).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="group_5" id="group_5" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">
  <option value="bitte" selected="selected" title="fake">Bitte wählen</option>
  <option value="35" title="Stoffbeutel">Stoffbeutel 28</option>
  <option value="36" title="Plastikbeutel">Plastikbeutel 28</option>
</select>

<div class="lagerbestand-attribute">
  <div class="Stoffbeutel"> Stoffbeutel: 5 Stücke</div>
  <div class="Plastikbeutel"> Plastikbeutel: 5 Stücke</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats amazing! Thanks a lot for this solution!

Answer (score 0):

very simple, do it like

```
$('.lagerbestand-attribute div').hide();
$('#group_5').change(function(){
    var $lagerbestand =  $('.lagerbestand-attribute').find('div').hide().end();
    $lagerbestand.find("."+$(this).find("option:selected").attr('title')).show();
});
```

What actually happening in the code is :

- First of all hiding all the div control
- then on selection change finding the title attribute from selected option and showing the corresponding section